# Count on a database using Count function SQL

Tags: sql, count

I have the database schema like this

```
Flights(flno,from,to,distance,departs,arrives,price)
Aircraft(aid,aname,cruisingRange)
Certified(employee,aircraft)
Employees(eid,ename,salary)
```

Where Flno is primary key and Each route corresponds to a "flno".

So I have this question to answer for the Schema

For each pilot, list their employee ID, name, and the number of routes
he can pilot.

I have this SQL, is this correct? ( I can test, as I dont have data for the database).

```
 select eid, ename, count(flno) 
 from employees, flights 
 groupby flno
```

Comment: No, it's not quite right because you don't have any `JOIN` criteria.  This will give you the Cartesian product of all employees and flights.  You would discover this if you  tested it.  You can test it by inserting data into the tables and then analyzing the results of the query.

Comment: Your schema is missing a relation between the flights and the aircrafts

Comment: What are your foreign keys between the tables? Is `Certified.employee` related to `Employees.eid` or `Employees.ename`? Is `Certified.aircraft` related to `Aircraft.aid` or `Aircraft.aname`? I'm guessing the id columns?

Comment: Also, the column names are a bit hard to read.  It's clear that `aid` means aircraft_id when the same line above shows it's on the `aircraft` table, but when you have a query joining several tables, `aid` is going to get confusing to anyone with poor short-term memory (like me).  Couldn't these be named `aircraft_id`, `employee_id`, etc?

Comment: There is nothing in Flight that links to Employee (nor aircraft).  How can you expect to do what you are asking?

Comment: `certified.employee` relates to `employees.eid` and  and `certified.aircraft` `aircraft.aid`

Comment: its a homeworks, and and i m just learning SQL. so we havent played with databases yet

Comment: Okay. Check out SQLZoo and MySQLTutorial and the MySQL reference guide to learn, SQLFiddle lets you experiment with stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple questioin, but as everyone is mentioning you don't have any link between employee and flights. The relationships stop at `certified`.

You obviously have or will create some relationship. I have written a query that will give you the count taking into account that you will have a many to many relationship between employee and flights. Meaning an employee can have many flights and a single flight can be made by many employees.

Flights(flno,from,to,distance,departs,arrives,price)
Aircraft(aid,aname,cruisingRange)
Certified(employee,aircraft)
Employees(eid,ename,salary)

```
select
  e.eid employee_id,
  e.ename employee_name,
  count(*)
from
  employees e 

  inner join certified c on
    c.employee = e.eid

  inner join aircraft a on
    a.aid = c.aircraft

  inner join aircraft_flights af on -- new table that you would need to create
    af.aircraft = a.aid and

  inner join flights f on
    f.flno = af.flno -- not I made up a relationship here which needs to exist in some for or another
group by
  e.eid,
  e.ename
```

I hope this at least shows you how to write a count statement correctly, but you should probably brush up on your understanding of [joins](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/).

Hope that helps.

EDIT

Without the relationships and working in your comments you could get the count as below.

```
select
  e.eid employee_id,
  e.ename employee_name,
  count(*)
from
  employees e 

  inner join certified c on
    c.employee = e.eid

  inner join aircraft a on
    a.aid = c.aircraft

  inner join flights f on
    f.distance <= a.cruisingRange
group by
  e.eid,
  e.ename
```

Comment: hey, Thanks for your answer. But I m thinking like this `Link employees.eid with certified.employee` then
`Link certified.aircraft with aircraft.aid` 
Then find fights where `flights.distance <= aircraft.cruisingRange`. Because i ve been told A ploit is ok to pilot a route if the `cruisingRange >= Flights.distance.`

Any advice on this?

Comment: Sure will just adjust answer quick.